# Developing a data access layer using ADO.Net and LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

I have a potential project where I would be working on developing the "Data Access Layer" of a reporting application using ADO.Net and LINQToSQL.

I have not specifically worked on a ***Data Access Layer*** project (middle tier), so I was wondering if anyone here could provide a sample / example / resource, where I can get an idea of what the project entails.

Comment: If you are just starting the project you should probably use the Entity Framework instead of LINQtoSQL.  EF is more future-proofed, LinqToSql was just a temporary solution until the EF was ready for primetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi take a look at this really good article:

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/476/n-layered-web-applications-with-aspnet-35-part-1-general-introduction

Comment: I really like this article, it describes a whole architecture step by step. This article is also available for .net 2.0.